# php cache dynamic index page

Tags: php, mysql, caching

I found [phpfastcahce](http://www.phpfastcache.com/) class for cached MySQL result. in details that support WinCache, MemCache, Files, X-Cache, APC Cache and say:

`PHP Caching Class For Database : Your website have 10,000 visitors who are online, and your dynamic page have to send 10,000 same queries to database on every page load. With phpFastCache, your page only send 1 query to DB, and use the cache to serve 9,999 other visitors.`

in sample code:

```
<?php
    // In your config file
    include("php_fast_cache.php");
    // This is Optional Config only. You can skip these lines.
    // phpFastCache support "apc", "memcache", "memcached", "wincache" ,"files", "pdo", "mpdo" and "xcache"
    // You don't need to change your code when you change your caching system. Or simple keep it auto
    phpFastCache::$storage = "auto";
    // End Optionals

    // In your Class, Functions, PHP Pages
    // try to get from Cache first.
    $products = phpFastCache::get("products_page");

    if($products == null) {
        $products = YOUR DB QUERIES || GET_PRODUCTS_FUNCTION;
        // set products in to cache in 600 seconds = 10 minutes
        phpFastCache::set("products_page",$products,600);
    }

    foreach($products as $product) {
        // Output Your Contents HERE
    }
?>
```

NOW, In my index of my website I have any block for show last news, best news, world news ..... for cache my index, i must cache `MySQL` result for each block`(last news, best news, world news ..... )` using phpfastcache and in admin page remove all cache if I edit existing news Or add new news? this is a true way?

what's best way For cache `MySQL` result my index page using **phpfastcache**(any method)?!

Comment: Not specific to phpfastcache (with which I am not familiar), but generally when working with any cache you need to have a strategy around how to deal with cache misses (i.e. query DB and populate cache with result) and to deal with invalidating/purging items from the cache (purge cache entries upon changing to underlying data, apply TTL's for cache items), etc.

Comment: did answer solve your problem ?

Answer (score 1):

phpfastcache cant uderstand your data was changed or not

you must do something after specific data changed in your database

first in your home page cache code must be like this :

```
$lastnews = phpFastCache::get('index_lastnews');
$bestnews = phpFastCache::get('index_bestnews');
$worldnews = phpFastCache::get('index_worldnews');

if($lastnews == null) {
    $lastnews = YOUR DB QUERIES || GET_DATA_FUNCTION;
    phpFastCache::set('index_lastnews',$lastnews,600);
}
if($bestnews == null) {
    $bestnews = YOUR DB QUERIES || GET_DATA_FUNCTION;
    phpFastCache::set('index_bestnews',$bestnews,600);
}
```

.
.
.

and in your admin page when specific data changed cache code must be like this :

```
AFTER DATABASE insert | update ....
```

you can replace old cache by this two way :

1) delete cache (after delete cache , cache automatically rebuild after first visit)

```
phpFastCache::delete('index_lastnews');
```

2) update cache

```
$lastnews =   YOUR DB QUERIES || GET_DATA_FUNCTION;
phpFastCache::set("index_lastnews",$lastnews,600);
```